# MQTT lost connect

Tags: java, tcp, mqtt

I am trying to build an simple application that receive latitude and longitude of a location, and then return the Address of that location. The application have 2 part: The Android app and the Analytic app. The Client's Android app will send the latitude and longtude to CloudMQTT, and Analytic app will receive the latitude and longtude from CloudMQTT, analyze and then send the result to the Client's Android app VIA TCP. But the problem is, when i add the sendResultTCPAnalytic function (the function that send result from analytic app to client via TCP) to the run function, the MQTT connection lost ERROR appear. But when i exclude the sendResult function and only show what on the cloud, the connect run normal.Can someone explain it to me. Thank you. Sorry for my bad English, i am not a native speaker. 
Here is my MQTT code:

```
public void run() {        
        try {
            mqttClient = new MqttClient(broker, "AnalyticApp");
            MqttConnectOptions connOpts = new MqttConnectOptions();
            connOpts.setCleanSession(false);
            connOpts.setUserName(username);
            connOpts.setPassword(password.toCharArray());

            noticeBoard.append("Connecting to " + broker + "\n");

            String topic = "Assignment";
            mqttClient.setCallback(new MqttCallback() {

                public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
                    String data = new String(message.getPayload());
                    String[] field = data.split(",");

                    boolean isDuplicate = false;
                    Device newDevice = new Device(field);
                    for (int index = 0; index < devices.size(); index++) {
                        if (devices.get(index).id.equals(field[0])) {
                            isDuplicate = true;
                            devices.remove(index);
                            devices.add(index, newDevice);
                        }
                    }

                    if (!isDuplicate || devices.isEmpty()) {
                        devices.add(newDevice);
                    }
                    noticeBoard.append(" " + "\n");

                    noticeBoard.setText("");
                    for (int index=0;index<devices.size();index++) {
                        do {
                        GeoCoding temp=new GeoCoding();
                        devices.get(index).resultaddress=temp.getAddress(devices.get(index).latitude+","+devices.get(index).longitude);
                        }while(devices.get(index).resultaddress==null);             
                        }
                    for (int index = 0; index < devices.size(); index++) {
                        noticeBoard.append(devices.get(index).id + "\t"
                                + devices.get(index).longitude + "\t"
                                + devices.get(index).latitude + "\t"
                                + devices.get(index).portTCP + "\t"
                                +devices.get(index).resultaddress+"\n"
                                );
                        sendResultTCPAnalytic(devices.get(0).id, 3333, devices.get(0).resultaddress);

                    }
                }

                public void connectionLost(Throwable cause) {
                    noticeBoard.append("Connection to broker lost!" + cause.getMessage() + "\n");
                }

                public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken token) {
                }

            });


            while (true) {
                mqttClient.connect(connOpts);
                mqttClient.subscribe(topic, 1);
            }

        } catch (MqttException me) {
            noticeBoard.append(me.getMessage() + "\n");
        }
    }
```

And here is my sendResultTCPAnalytic code:

```
public void sendResultTCPAnalyticServer(String host, int port,String result) throws Exception
    {       

        Socket socketOfClient;
        try
        {

            socketOfClient = new Socket(host, port); /*CREATE SOCKET*/
            OutputStream os = socketOfClient.getOutputStream();
                    try
                   {
                        String dataToSend = null;
                        if ((result) != null)
                        {
                            dataToSend = result;
                            os.write(dataToSend.getBytes());
                        } else
                        {

                            socketOfClient.close();

                        }
                        socketOfClient.close();
                    } catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }         
        } catch (UnknownHostException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Here is the error:

```
Connection to broker lost!MQTT Exception
```

Comment: 2 Questions. 1) Are there any error logs with any stacktraces? 2) which use a separate TCP connection to send results and not just publish them to the broker so the client can subscribe?

Comment: @hardillb: 1) My app said: Connection to broker lost!MQTT Exception.
2) Actually this is my assignment, they said that i must send the result from analytic app to android app via TCP

Comment: Edit the question to include the execption and the stack trace so we can see what caused it.